# Why gnome-software is saying that Atom is proprietary?

Tags: software-center, license, atom

I opened `gnome-software` to install Atom. This is the screen I get:

[image]

`gnome-software` is saying that Atom is proprietary software, but the [Github repo](https://github.com/atom/atom) reports the license as being MIT license, which AFAIK is GPL-compatible.

Comment: Old(ish) bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1778607

Answer (score 0):

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1778607 it is caused by using unclear "Other Open Source" in license field in their `snap` package.

To change this either display of this field would need to change (bug mentioned above is open since 2018) or whoever maintains `snap` package should set license to be more specific.

Also, note that some projects have open source core but release versions with proprietary elements. And release is not openly licensed - see Visual Studio Code which is not being released under open license and Codium, build only from open source without proprietary parts.